# formula of spectral fractional laplacian

Tags: ap.analysis-of-pdes, fractional-calculus

In fact, if $U$ is a solution of 
\begin{equation}
  \ \  \left\{\begin{aligned}
 (-\Delta)^s  U &=f  &&\text{in }  \Omega \\
 U  &= g  &&\text{on }  \partial \Omega \\
 \end{aligned}
  \right.
\end{equation}
Is it possible to write $U$ explicitly in terms of $f$ and $g\neq 0$ where $s\in (0, 1).$

Comment: This is NOT the fractional Laplacian!

Comment: Actually, this is a similar type of Caffarelli--Silvestre extension for the fractional Laplacian.

Comment: I believe the answer is "no", unless perhaps $\Omega$ is very special (half-space, strip). Note that if $w = 0$, then $U(x, 0) = (-\Delta_\Omega)^{-s} g(x)$, where $\Delta_\Omega$ is the Dirichlet Laplacian. The Green function of $\Omega$ (i.e. the kernel of $(-\Delta_\Omega)^{-1}$) is known explicitly only in a few special cases, and finding the kernel of $(-\Delta_\Omega)^{-s}$ seems to be even more difficult.